# Using windbg,how to read assembly back and forth?

Tags: windbg

```
0:000> u execute
php5ts!execute:
100205d0 51              push    ecx
100205d1 8b0da8f35310    mov     ecx,dword ptr [php5ts!executor_globals_id (1053f3a8)]
100205d7 55              push    ebp
100205d8 8b6c2410        mov     ebp,dword ptr [esp+10h]
100205dc c644240700      mov     byte ptr [esp+7],0
100205e1 8b4500          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp]
100205e4 8b4488fc        mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+ecx*4-4]
100205e8 8b88c4020000    mov     ecx,dword ptr [eax+2C4h]
0:000> 
php5ts!execute:
100205d0 51              push    ecx
100205d1 8b0da8f35310    mov     ecx,dword ptr [php5ts!executor_globals_id (1053f3a8)]
100205d7 55              push    ebp
100205d8 8b6c2410        mov     ebp,dword ptr [esp+10h]
100205dc c644240700      mov     byte ptr [esp+7],0
100205e1 8b4500          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp]
100205e4 8b4488fc        mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+ecx*4-4]
100205e8 8b88c4020000    mov     ecx,dword ptr [eax+2C4h]
```

I'm using `u execute` to disassemble ,but as you see the line no doesn't increment each time.

What's wrong in my operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing enter repeats the previous command, so essentially you're repeating the `u execute` command. To continue listing do `u execute`, then `u` and then enter will repeat that.